# Front end login and page restriction

Tags: users, user-roles, private, content-restriction

I've read a few posts about this topic, but I haven't found any plugins that fit my need.

What I want to achieve:

User A and B both have a login. When user A logs in, he's redirected to www.somesite.com/**a**/ and when user B logs in, he's redirected to www.somesite.com/**b**/

Now, www.somesite.com/**a**/ should be private for user A, and user B or anyone else should not be able to access this page.

I found this plugin that would allow a redirect after login: 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirect-after-login/screenshots/

But as you can see, this is only for the standard user roles.

I will of course need some custom members/groups, since I could have many users that should only be able to see their own personal page (Right now my need is only around 7 users). It is very important that I, as an admin, can control the content on these pages. It shouldn't just be a simple "update profile page".

So yeah, to sum up: I need each user to have a private page, that they are redirected to when they login.

I hope that someone has tried this before, and has some ideas. I don't think there's one plugin that can do all I'm looking for, so I guess I need a couple of plugins that can talk well together.

Please do tell if I need to provide more information.

Comment: Have you looked at [Customer Area](https://wordpress.org/plugins/customer-area/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Buddypress to achieve this along with this plugin:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/bp-redirect-to-profile/

Hope that helps.